# What is the smoke from KNO3 with sugar reaction?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

So I was doing a reaction between $\pu{0.02mol}$ $\ce{KNO3}$ and $\pu{0.01mol}$ $\ce{C6H12O6}$ and there was a smoke. What is the chemical reaction, and what is the smoke?

Comment: Is it smoke or steam?

Comment: @Waylander it is smoke. It looks like the smoke that comes from wood fires.

Comment: It isn't C6H12O2, it's C6H12O6.

Answer (score 0):

It should be some mixture of N2, K2CO3, CO2, H2O, and some other things.